# How to get all nodes affected by some node in Maya?

Tags: maya

In Maya, when you have the option "display affected" turned ON, the nodes affected by the selected node turns pink in the viewport. Is there a way to get a list of those nodes?

To be more specific, what a need is to test if I animate or change an attribute value in node_A, will it affect node_B?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways this can work.  Depending on what you want to know:

1. The `listHistory` command can show you which nodes are upstream or downstream of a given node.
2. The `listConnections` command will explicitly track connections between attributes and nodes. This one reflects the actual structure of the hypergraph for your objects. It may include a lot of intermediate nodes which you would have to traverse.

`ListHistory` is mostly used for geometry nodes (such as deformers or modifiers) and `listConnections` is used for node and attribute connections

Answer (score 0):

There is a command called [*affects*](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/affects-html.html). This command will tell you what output values a selected attribute affects. You can then recursively fetch those attributes connections an traverse further using *listConnections*.